# Serialize dynamics ax 365 data contract extension

Tags: serialization, axapta, x++, dynamics-365-operations

I am trying to serialize some JSON input to a data contract in Microsoft Dynamics 365 Finance. A simple data contract class works fine, but I cannot get data contract extensions to work. Does any one have experience with this or perhaps a working example?

The only related information I managed to find on this topic comes from [this forum post](https://community.dynamics.com/365/financeandoperations/f/dynamics-365-for-finance-and-operations-forum/240773/class-extension-of-data-contract-class-d365).
Follow some hyperlinks and you will end up with the [official Microsoft documentation (Ref# 199219)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/October18/dynamics365-finance-operations/platform-extensibility4), which states that this should be supported.

All variations of the data contract attributes below compile fine, but proved unsuccessful for me:

- Using `DataContract` and `DataMember` instead of `DataContractAttribute` and `DataMemberAttribute`.
- Combining `DataContract` and `DataContractAttribute` on a single method. (Produces runtime error about double serialization attribute.)
- Repeating the `DataContractAttribute` on the extension class.

Additional experiments with the [JSON deserializer class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer) through its various constructor options also proved unsuccessful:

- Passing a list of known types `ClassA` and `ClassA_Extension`.
- Passing a list of known types `ClassA_Extension` and `ClassA` (in case the list order had an impact).
- Passing a settings object and explicitly setting `IgnoreExtensionDataObject` to `false` (this appears to be the default).
- Passing the extension class type as first parameter.

---

### Update

A ticket was raised with Microsoft to investigate the issue. In their response they mentioned that they were able to reproduce this. They also declared that this was *"by design"* and *"will not be fixed"*.

Our final solution will most likely be the following:

1. Build a mapping of `DataMemberAttribute` values and the corresponding data contract method.
2. Use a `JavaScriptSerializer` object to turn the JSON into a nested .NET dictionary object.
3. Iterate over the dictionary object and populate the data contract with the help of the mapping.

---

### Example

Below is a miminal example to demonstrate my issue. The values of the variables `value1` and `value2` are populated as expected, but variable `value3` remains empty.

**Data contract**

```
[DataContractAttribute('Class A')]
public class ClassA
{
    protected str value1;
    protected str value2;

    [DataMemberAttribute('Value1')]
    public str value1(str _value1 = value1)
    {
        value1 = _value1;
        return value1;
    }

    [DataMemberAttribute('Value2')]
    public str value2(str _value2 = value2)
    {
        value2 = _value2;
        return value2;
    }

}
```

**Data contract extension**

```
[ExtensionOf(classStr(ClassA))]
public final class ClassA_Extension
{
    private str value3;

    [DataMemberAttribute('Value3')]
    public str value3(str _value3 = value3)
    {
        value3 = _value3;
        return value3;
    }

}
```

**Serialization code** with hard-coded input

```
public class ClassTest
{
    public static void main(Args _args)
    {
        str inputJSON =   @'{
                                "Value1": "abc",
                                "Value2": "def",
                                "Value3": "ghi"
                            }';

        ClassA ret = new ClassA();

        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding::UTF8.GetBytes(inputJSON));

        System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer dcjSer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(ret.GetType());

        ret = dcjSer.ReadObject(ms);

        ms.Close();
    }

}
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the serializer is having issues. You might be able to pass a `Type` array similar to how `FormRunConfigurationPropertyClassList` does it?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the input! I had a look at the JSON serializer and provided some additional parameters. Unfortunately without success... I have added the things I tried to the question description.

Comment: It looks like a bug :(

Comment: That is what I feared. If I get any feedback through a Microsoft ticket, then I will update this question.

Comment: Microsoft feedback has been added as an update section in the question...

Comment: @Sander I tweeted about it to see if anyone in the `AX` community has any additional thoughts or workarounds. May not get traction though. https://twitter.com/AlexOnDAX/status/1227269448949616640?s=20

Comment: Thank you for the extra effort! Unfortunately Joris' response settles it: serialization through .NET features is not supported.

Comment: Yup, sounds like it. You'll have to use another method or some of the built in things.

Answer (score 1):

From PU23 onwards, an inline assignment of the respective variable avoids the error ***"DataMemberAttributeOnExtensionClassNotSupported: The DataMemberAttribute is not supported on extension classes".***

This being the case, I suggest you change your ClassA_Extension to contain the following code:

```
[ExtensionOf(classStr(ClassA))]
public final class ClassA_Extension
{
    // Ensure you assign a value (initializing the variable).
    private str value3 = null;

    // The rest of your code... 
}
```

I'm doing a similar development currently but using DataContracts for non-ChainOfCommand extensions (natural inheritance) on 10.0.37 and it works perfectly without inline assignments so unless fixed throughout the versions released this is clearly a requirement of the Chain Of Command extension.

Reference: **https://erconsult.eu/blog/extending-sysoperation-contracts-with-datamemberattribute/**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the hyperlink behind your reference points to _this_ StackOverflow question... Could you please update your asnwer with the intended hyperlink?

Comment: Oopsies! Fixed eheh

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35393518)

Comment: I'll take care of transcribing the answer tonight. New to this, thank you for the feedback @RamChander